# SQL query: multiple count group by date

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have 2 tables in my mySQL database:

```
Table Sensor
_id    Name
1      Sensor1
2      Sensor2

Table History
_id    Sensor_fk    Date 
1      1            2015-05-24
2      2            2015-05-27
3      1            2015-05-28
4      1            2015-05-28
5      2            2015-05-28
...
```

I need a query that return something like this:

```
Date          Sensor1    Sensor2
2015-05-24    1          0
2015-05-27    0          1
2015-05-28    2          1
```

that is the count of my 2 sensors grouped by date. I will populate a bar chart with this data.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a UNION on two individual GROUP BY clauses for each Sensor. Like

```
(Select count(*) as Sensor1 from History h
     where h.Sensor_FK = 1
     group by DateField
)

Union

(Select Count(*) as Sensor2 from History h
    whre h.Sensor_FK = 2
    group by DateField
   )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It´s not working. I think I have to use PIVOT to invert my Sensor1 and Sensor2 into columns of my query. But I don´t know how

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
SELECT h.date as Date, 
count(CASE WHEN h.sensor_fk = 1 THEN h.sensor_fk END) as 'Sensor1',
count(CASE WHEN h.sensor_fk = 2 THEN h.sensor_fk END) as 'Sensor2'
FROM history h
GROUP BY Date
```